# Passed value from Spring controller to Thymeleaf template is not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In my controller, I have:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String root(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "test");
}
```

In the HTML, I have:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    var m = [[${message}]];
    alert(m);
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

I am using the following dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring3/3.0.6.RELEASE

I am using the following bean declaration:

```
<bean id="templateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
</bean>
```

When I load the page, it does not show the alert message. What am I not doing correctly here?

Comment: did you check page source or in console from browser to check whether `var m` assigned or not? Code seems okay

Comment: @Zico it says it's `undefined`

Comment: Am I missing any configuration steps?

Comment: Did you initiate bean of `SpringTemplateEngine`? i am not sure. I almost forgot about spring 3 thymeleaf

Comment: No, how do I do that?

Comment: You can see [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#the-springstandard-dialect)